# Is there a way to truncate or delete a table and associated foreign keys in hibernate PostgreSQL

Tags: java, postgresql, hibernate, jpa

`TRUNCATE demo_table CASCADE` query works in SQL client, but it doesn't seem to work in hibernate PostgreSQL dialect. I am not sure why that is, so I truncate a table in hibernate using: `DELETE FROM table_name` and it works fine.

```
public demoManager deleteTable() {
    entityManager = crud.begin();
    entityManager.createQuery("delete from demo_table").executeUpdate();
    entityManager.getTransaction().commit();
    return this;
  }
```

Now, the problem is that it only works fine in hibernate if the table's primary key is not a foreign key in another table. If its primary key exists is a foreign key in another table, the test fails and an error is thrown:

```
Caused by: org.postgresql.util.PSQLException: ERROR: update or delete on table "demo_table" violates foreign key constraint "hui6ys16oiwt19pfkw0fxfaovea" on table "demo_table_two"
```

Adding `CASCADE` resolved the primary/foreign key issue in the SQL client, so I tried doing the same in hibernate:

`TRUNCATE demo_table CASCADE` but got a compilation error: `TRUNCATE unexpected`

I also tried this: `DELETE FROM demo_table CASCADE` but `CASCADE` is not recognised at runtime.

How do I truncate or delete a table in hibernate PostgreSQL dialect and delete any associated foreign key as part of the process?

Answer (score 0):

`TRUNCATE` is not part of HQL, therefore you cannot use it with `entityManager.createQuery`.

You can run the query as a native SQL query:

```
entityManager.createNativeQuery("TRUNCATE demo_table CASCADE").executeUpdate();
```

Comment: I tried that but got a compilation error `No data sources are configured to run this SQL` even though I have a data source already configured in my persistence.xml. How do I get it to read my existing data source so I don't manually have to configure another one? Also, do I need to do any additional configuration in my entity class to use a native query?

Comment: That’s a completely unrelated error. Something is wrong with the configuration of your project. As long as you have an entityManager, any SQL query should work